# Can I create a ListView with dynamic GroupItemCount?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, listview

I'm using the new ASP.Net ListView control to list database items that will be grouped together in sections based on one of their columns like so:

```
region1
    store1
    store2
    store3
region2
    store4
region3
    store5
    store6
```

Is this possible to do with the ListView's GroupItemTemplate? Every example I have seen uses a static number of items per group, which won't work for me. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the GroupItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used GroupItemCount, but I have taken this example written up by [Matt Berseth](http://mattberseth.com/) titled [Building a Grouping Grid with the ASP.NET 3.5 LinqDataSource and ListView Controls](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html) and have grouped items by a key just like you want.

It involves using an outer and inner ListView control.  Works great, give it a try.

Comment: I was hoping the ListView could do this without nesting another control, but if not that's how I would accomplish this. Just trying to keep the design simple.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're doing a DataBind **AFTER** setting the GroupItemCount property. I had the same problem and that's what I did to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using GroupItemCount programmatically but it didn't give me the expected results.

I followed Otto's suggestion and implemented an outer and inner ListView control. This seems to be the best available solution.